# Use different files depending on desired build environment

Tags: reactjs

I'm aware of environmental variables, but I'm attempting to use a different file all together.

I'm going to have two urls, one that is more for users to log in and create/modify information, and another for the public to access. As a result, I'm needing two different builds, one where the app.js with routing is used, and another where app.js without is used. Is this possible?

You may be asking, why not just use two different projects. The single page the public will access is also something I want the private site to access and "demo" the new information they are creating before publishing it. As a result I need it to use the same page more or less.

I remember something like this having been done with config files at a past position I worked at, but that was a few years ago and I can't find anything similar.

Comment: I'd actually be asking why not use a normal authorization/authentication mechanism.

Comment: I currently have the application wrapped by an azure ad auth in the app.js file (so the router is wrapped too). Hence why I want to use a different app.js for the public build.